# Install MFP 7.1 CLI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to install MFP 7.1 CLI using the following URL:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/using-cli-to-create-build-and-manage-mobilefirst-project-artifacts/

All my platform is set for npm, but when I run npm install -g mfpdev-cli,

mfp 8.0 is getting installed instead.

```
$ mfpdev -v

8.0.0-201603280000
```

How can I get the MFP 7.1 CLI package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not installing the CLI for v8.0... although they can co-exist.

You can download the CLI for v7.1 from here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_7.1.0.zip
Or get the very latest iFix from IBM Fix Central.